# Running java code, which uses classes from other package

Tags: java

I have the following directory layout: 
The program folder contains java, class, and pack folders and my current location is program/java, which contains a.java and b.java files. Initially class and pack contains nothing.

b.java

```
package comm.domm;
public class b
{
    public void bFu()
    {
        System.out.println("b function");
    }
}
```

a.java

```
package com.dom;
import comm.domm.*;
class a
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        (new b()).bFu();
        System.out.println("Utsab");
    }
}
```

Now, from program/java issue the following commands

```
javac -d ../pack b.java
javac -cp ../pack -d ../class a.java
```

Which creates comm/domm under pack and places b.class in program/pack/comm/domm
and creates com/dom under class and places a.class in program/class/com/dom

now from the same current directory I issue,

```
java -cp ../class;../pack com.dom.a
```

Which does not work, it can locate a.class but not b.class(b.class is required by a.class, as described in the source code) this time but while compiling a.java using

```
javac -cp ../pack -d ../class a.java
```

It could locate b.class and produced a.class, then why b.class is not found when I tried to run a.class?? How it can be found?
b.class is found during compilation but not at run time, why??

Comment: Can you post the exact exception you get?

Comment: As it looks like you're running on unix, that should probably be:  ../class:../pack  (separate with colons, not semicolons).

Comment: am running on cygwin, that gives unix environment in windows and it takes ; not :. am unable to attach the screen shot, as it's saying "u need @ least 10 reputations!", it could be more clear if i could upload that....

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : it's showing me java -help's output, then -bash: ../pack: is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a typo

```
javac -cp ../pack -d ../class b.java
```

You haven't compiled `a.java` at all. If you have

```
javac -cp ../pack -d ../class a.java
```

instead, then it's working for me and prints

```
b function
Utsab
```

as expected.

Comment: in this case u are putting a.class & b.class both in program/class but i wanted to put a.class in program/class and b.class in program/pack.....any ways mt logic was correct, it was a problem with the environment, after changing the environment it worked nicely, with out any change....thanks all

Answer (score 0):

my logic was correct, it was a problem with the environment, after changing the environment it worked nicely, with out any change....thanks all

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).